Is there a package manager in Azure Pipeline to Copy content files from nuget source into a .NET Framework project?
I have a .NET Framework 4.8 web service project, it has jquery packages in it.  When I use Visual Studio to install the packages, the script and theme files are automatically copied from the packages to the project.  From a fresh clone of the code I can issue "Update-Package -reinstall" and it will download and copy the packaged files to the appropriate project folders.
Unfortunately, Visual Studio Package Manager is not available in my Azure pipeline.  Package Manager commands can not be inserted into pre-build steps because they can not be executed by MS Build.  NuGet install can download the packages to the packages folder but does not copy the script and theme files from the packages to the project folder.
Relevant parts of my YML, which does download the packages but does not modify the project files:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Nuget Install'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    arguments: 'install  ./MyProject/packages.config'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet Restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

Is there an alternative nuget command or package manager that I can use to do this without having manual copy steps in my yml or csproj?  The most straightforward alternative is to check in all the jquery files after they copy to the project folders, which has its own maintenance issues.
